# How do I add a field to a Prolog (Pengines) response?

Tags: javascript, json, prolog, response

I'm building a simple game on a prolog server running on Pengines. I have a template that gives a response to my javascript code with a Board field as `response.data[0].Board`, but I can't add an extra field when I need to return some other information.

I guessed that it would be available in the response when I called a function that assigns a value.

In my game.pl file I have: (hard coded values for example's sake)

```
calculateScores(Board,B,N):- 
  B=5,
  N=7.
```

...And javascript calls:

```
pengine.ask("calculateScores("+Pengine.stringify(gridData)+",B, N)");
```

My javascript code has this working:

```
gridData = response.data[0].Board‘
```

but I'd need to also call:

```
whiteScore = response.data[0].B;
blackScore = response.data[0].N;
```

What I should be able to do is fetch 5 and 7 (in this case) from the Prolog response to my javascript code.

I believe there's some middle step I'm missing, but I cannot sort it out.